# Making a dataframe wide format based on the number of days from index date(s)

Tags: r, date, wide-format-data

I am trying to figure out how to make multiple customer orders placed within 120 days wide format for each customer. If a customer has orders placed over the course of several year, then there are multiple intervals of 120 days, so each customer may have multiple rows, with each row corresponding to an interval of 120 days from an index date. Thank you!

I have a dataframe:

```
customerid <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2")
orderid <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")
orderdate <- c("2020-05-19", "2020-09-08", "2020-09-16", "2020-12-21", "2021-01-03", "2020-08-21","2020-11-22","2021-02-01")
df <- data.frame(customerid, orderid, orderdate)
```

The result should be:

[image]

Edit: With the 1st solution, when there are serial dates that fall within 120 days of each other consecutively, they are listed in the same row even if some dates are >120 days apart. I updated the dataframe with dates that don't work with the 1st solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr) # v1.1.0+ for .by
df %>%
  mutate(orderdate = as.Date(orderdate),
         customer_era = cumsum(orderdate - lag(orderdate, default = as.Date("2000-01-01")) > 120),
         .by = customerid) %>%
  mutate(instance = row_number(), .by = c(customerid, customer_era)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = instance, names_glue = "{.value}_{.name}",
              values_from = c(orderid, orderdate))
```

Or version that'd work with earlier dplyr:

```
df %>%
  group_by(customerid) %>%
  mutate(orderdate = as.Date(orderdate),
         customer_era = cumsum(orderdate - lag(orderdate, default = as.Date("2000-01-01")) > 120)) %>%
  group_by(customerid, customer_era) %>%
  mutate(instance = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = instance, names_glue = "{.value}_{.name}",
              values_from = c(orderid, orderdate))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 × 8
  customerid customer_era orderid_orderid_1 orderid_orderid_2 orderid_orderid_3 orderdate_orderdate_1 orderdate_orderdate_2 orderdate_orderdate_3
  <chr>             <int> <chr>             <chr>             <chr>             <date>                <date>                <date>               
1 A1                    1 1                 2                 NA                2018-09-14            2018-09-15            NA                   
2 A1                    2 3                 4                 5                 2019-09-15            2020-01-02            2020-01-03           
3 A2                    1 6                 NA                NA                2018-08-10            NA                    NA                   
4 A2                    2 7                 8                 NA                2020-08-21            2020-08-22            NA
```

Comment: Are you using an earlier version of dplyr? Prior to 1.1, you would use `group_by() %>% [mutate step] %>% ungroup()` to apply grouping to a single step of a chain.

Comment: Hard for me to imagine why without more info. Perhaps you could identify one or more customers for whom that happens, and include sample data with whatever characteristics you observe there? Some ideas: arrange the data by date before the lag calculation in case transactions not in order? Check for duplicate order dates for a customer?

Comment: Are you sure the customerid matches? ie could one have a trailing space or anything like that? Same capitalization?

Comment: Can you include a subset of source data that produces those problematic entries? I believe you that there is an issue with my code not working for your data, but the screen shot doesn't give me any information to troubleshoot.

Comment: That situation sounds ambiguous. Let's say your data had two years' of monthly dates. Certainly lots of those are 120 days apart, but none are 120 apart from the prior observation. I think you need to define your desired behavior more precisely.

Comment: For ease of viewing, I consolidated my replies in the comments section; please see my post above. Thanks!